# Issue with EnumWindows

Tags: c#, winapi

When enumerating windows using EnumWindows, I get hundreds of handles instead of one per open window on my desktop.

First of all, i am curious if this is the correct behavior.

Secondly, trying to get a difference between open windows before and after launching a process returns 15-20 new handles. I am wondering if there is a way to filter these based on some flag, i really need just the mainwindow handle.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the main window of a process, use the [`Process.MainWindowHandle` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle.aspx).

To answer your question, you can see exactly what all of the handles are using Spy++.
In short, *many* applications will create hidden windows to run message loops.

Comment: +1, still, keep in mind that there's no such a thing as a "main window" for a process, IIRC MainWindowHandle just retrieves the first top-level visible window created by the application it can find. This usually isn't a big problem, but for application which create several top-level windows (e.g. Outlook) it may give incorrect results.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter within the enum callback by checking [`IsWindowVisible()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633530%28VS.85%29.aspx) & ignoring invisible system/message sink windows.

Comment: How would you do that? 
"ignoring invisible system/message sink windows"
ty!