# how can I kill a process by its window title name in c#

Tags: c#

Guys how can I kill a process by its title name in c#. Say the title of Internet Explorer window is MSN | USA - Hotmail, Messenger...

I am making a small task manager like app that can kill an app with its title.

Comment: please show some source code... what have you tried ? what is not working ?

Comment: What if multiple windows have the same title?

Answer (score 5):

You can get all the IE processes, and then cycle through them, and check the windowtitle.
Something like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process[] IEProcesses = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("iexplore.exe");
        foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process CurrentProcess in IEProcesses)
        {
            if (CurrentProcess.MainWindowTitle.Contains("MSN | USA - Hotmail, Messenger"))
            {
                CurrentProcess.Kill();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Give full working C# sample please. (lot of time waste to search and not finding the right answer)

Answer (score 0):

You need to research the `EnumWindows` P-Invoke function.

Start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx

Then go here: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.EnumWindows
, and here: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.GetWindowText

Finally here: [Issue with EnumWindows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970184/issue-with-enumwindows)

Comment: Actually, Nicolai's answer is a better one, since it doesn't require P-Invoke.