# Running an EXE with a set WindowTitle

Tags: cmd, labview

I'm currently trying to run an exe, then find the PID of the process.  The easiest way to do this I thought would be to give it a unique windowtitle

running

`cmd /c start "testWindow" test.exe`

Always seems to create a process with WindowTitle "GDI+ Window (test.exe)"...  I'm still really new to this type of windows CLI, but I can't use a lot of fancy tools as I'm interfacing through a different program (LabVIEW).  Any help on how to get the WindowTitle to actually be used instead of just the exe's title?  Thanks!

Comment: On my machine (Win 10 Pro), this produces a window with the title `testWindow - test.exe`, and _not_ `Window (test.exe)` as you claim. What version of Windows are you running? How do you plan to find the process ID, anyway? You should be able to use `tasklist /FI "WindowTitle eq testWindow*"` to match the beginning of the title. If you can use PowerShell instead, you can get the PID directly after launching with [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.4)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67174392/62576

Comment: I'm doing through LabVIEW's SystemExec function, which I'm told is not the exact same as on the Windows CLI.  I'm on Win10, but I don't think I'll be able to use Powershell.  I was planning on using tasklist with a filter, but seeing as I can't get the title to change, it doesn't return anything currently.  Sorry I'm still a bit new to this, are you typing that exact command into the windows cmd?  I did replace the actual exe and parameters with test.exe to make it easier to read, maybe that's it?  It's a MatLAB compiled EXE if that makes any difference